# How to create stream from string in React and send it to self hosted wcf service with using JSONP

Tags: reactjs, wcf, stream, self

I developing a React application which using JSONP for communicate with my self hosted WCF service (vb.net).

I have a text such as

```
{
"name": "John",
"surname": "IRONHEART"
"job":"Freelancer"
.
.
.
.
}
```

I believe that I have to change string to stream and before send to WCF service because my string is being very long always.

My sample codes below.

Client

```
componentDidMount() {
     jsonp('http://myserver/myservice/getStreamedText?mytext=' + mystreamedtext );
}
```

WCF Service

```
<OperationContract, Webget(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
Public Function getStreamedText(Byval mytext as stream) as System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message

  ''HERE to access mytext 

End Function
```

I must convert string into stream in React Client App.
and also I must convert stream into string in WCF service

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: Since your client have very long string as parameter , it is not suitable to receive the parameter using get method , could you change it to post method?